# How do bounding boxes work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

I want to include a histogram into the first and second node with a bounding box and only text for the rest node.
Here's my work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,fit}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

            \begin{axis}[
                ybar=-0.10cm,
                axis x line*=bottom,
                axis y line*=left,
                height=3.5cm, width=3.4cm,
                bar width=0.1cm,
                symbolic x coords={topic1,topic2,topic3},
                %xtick={topic1,topic2,topic3},
                label style={font=\tiny},
                tick label style={font=\tiny}]
                \addplot[BlueGreen,fill] coordinates {(topic1,0.4)};
                \addplot[Cyan,fill] coordinates {(topic2,0.5)};
                \addplot[ForestGreen,fill] coordinates {(topic3,0.1)};
                
            \end{axis}
        (bounding box)
        \node[draw=red, fit=(current bounding box)](a){};
        \node[right = 4cm of a, draw=red,] (b) {sometext};
        \node[right = 4cm of b, draw=red,] (c) {sometext};


        
        \draw[->] ($(a.north east)!0.25!(a.south east)$) -- node[below] {arrow text} ($(b.north west)!0.25!(b.south west)$);
        \draw[->] ($(b.north east)!0.25!(b.south east)$) -- node[below] {arrow text} ($(c.north west)!0.25!(c.south west)$);
        %\draw(a.east)--++(2,0);



    % more arrows here
\end{tikzpicture}
%   \newpage
\end{document}
```

1. I don't know how to fit the bounding box again to the second node and also how the bounding box works?
2. How to fix the node size?

[image]

Comment: the requirement  is not quite clear --could you add a hand sketch of the desired output -- the line `(bounding box)` is supposed to be commented out in my previous answer -- `%(bounding box)`

Comment: I have updated my graphic output  I just have no idea how to put stuff inside the node
such as histograms, graphs, images.
The rest of it I think I can handle it thanks for your attention and help

Answer (score 1):

- Save complex contents of nodes, like `tikzpicture`s with `axis` environments, in a box and use these boxes inside another `tikzpicture`. Use the LaTeX commands `\newsavebox`, `\savebox` and `\usebox`; see e.g. [here](https://latexref.xyz/_005csbox-_0026-_005csavebox.html) for a description.
- You can set a minimum height and width of the nodes such that they do not collapse if there is not much text inside. In principle it is also possible to let LaTeX measure the size of the diagram and use it as minimum height and width, but this is probably an overkill for a one time drawing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\A
\savebox\A{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar=-0.10cm,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      axis y line*=left,
      height=3.5cm, width=3.4cm,
      bar width=0.1cm,
      symbolic x coords={topic1,topic2,topic3},
      %xtick={topic1,topic2,topic3},
      label style={font=\tiny}, tick label
      style={font=\tiny}]
      \addplot[BlueGreen,fill] coordinates {(topic1,0.4)};
      \addplot[Cyan,fill] coordinates {(topic2,0.5)};
      \addplot[ForestGreen,fill] coordinates {(topic3,0.1)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mynode/.style={draw=red,minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2cm}
  ]
  \node[mynode](a){\usebox\A};
  \node[mynode,right = 4cm of a] (b) {\usebox\A};
  \node[mynode,right = 4cm of b,align=center] (c) {some\\lines\\of\\text};
  \draw[->] (a) -- node[below] {arrow text} (b);
  \draw[->] (b) -- node[below] {arrow text} (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well, I use matrix forms.
I will also try the above method. Anyway thanks for your help